# What are some negative/positive aspects from globalization in regard to developed countries?

Tags: macroeconomics, international-trade

I have read many articles on how globalization is helping developing countries, as more and more companies from developed countries have been moving their production oversees. However, as hard as I tried, I couldn't find a lot of articles talking about the opposite site of the story - How globalization affects developed countries.

Most of the articles I found were focused on the fact that moving production oversees will increase the unemployment and decrease the GDP. However, are there any other aspects (positive or negative)? Would love to learn more about this topic and if you have a good article that dives into this I would be really grateful if you can provide me with a link to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a search in Google Scholar and it seems that most papers mainly digs into the benefits of less-developed countries regarding globalization.

But there are a couple of dimensions here that you can have a look:

**Globalization helps to reduce carbon emissions from international tourism** in the developed country following [Daniel,2020](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11356-019-07372-4)

**Impact of Globalization on some macro indicators** of developed countries of [Lenka,2013](http://ojs.spiruharet.ro/index.php/jedep/article/view/34)

**Developed-developing country partnerships**: Benefits to developed countries? from [Syed, 2012](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1186/1744-8603-8-17)

The **Globalization of the Software Industry**: **Perspectives and Opportunities for Developed and Developing Countries** from [Arora, 2005](https://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/abs/10.1086/ipe.5.25056169)

And last but not least, a great publication last year from [Gozgor,2020](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S030142152030121X) that prove that a higher level of economic g**lobalization promotes renewable energy** in developed countries

I went through 6 pages from Google Scholar, and my keyword is "**[globalization developed countries](https://scholar.google.com.vn/scholar?start=0&q=globalization%20developed%20countries&hl=vi&as_sdt=0,5)**" in case you want to replicate my search.